# Dynamics 365 Opportunity Product Suggestions Pane: 0x80041103 Query Build Error

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales

Ok so, I've inherited Dynamics 365 at a new work place and have become something of a defacto admin within the sales team as noone else has any prior experience in Power bi / apps.

I've been reconfiguring their Sales Hub app to align with how the company actually use the CRM but I've encountered an interesting issue which is present on both the Sales Hub app and their own "bespoke" app built by a previous external consultant. When you set up an opportunity, and add an opportunity product to said opportunity, the suggestions feature doesn't appear to work. In every field its returning a 0x80041103 Query Builder Error, and the product column is instead labelled as "a_8bd41b9db82ce911a98f00224801bcd3.name" and I can't find an answer as to why.

I've tested in both a production and sandbox environment, I've checked that the product being added has relationships with other products which would appear (cross sell / accessory etc) and all appears to be in order. I've also tried looking for where the suggestion pane is getting the.name from, but that's also a dead end. I've gone through the solution as well looking for any bespoke scripts that could be the cause, but also no luck.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further?